# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range') on my lock cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i tried the script about locking cells after first entry, but it doesn't works about TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')

i dont understand how to fix it.

```
function protectOnEdit(event) {

  var range = event.range();
  var description = 'Protected on ' + stringDate;
  var protection = range.protect().setDescription(description);

  // below code taken directly from Google's documentation (second comment is my own):

  // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
  // permission comes from a group, the script throws an exception upon removing the group.

  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  //user who installed trigger

  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851123/

Comment: Whenever we see these problems with on edit triggers, we always ask ourselves. How did the person execute the function and in this case, we assume that the person executed the function from the script editor. And that means that the function was not passed the event object without the event object, the range is undefined. So my recommendation is to read the above comment from TheMaster. he has covered a lot of triggering debug issues all in one article. If you read it carefully, you’ll probably understand how to debug it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) includes a `.range` field, but there is no `.range()` method there.

Replace:

```
  var range = event.range();
```

...with:

```
  const range = event.range;
```

Better yet, just use `event.range` in place of `range`, and remove the above declaration line altogether.